Angular signal is not triggering change in the template
@Component({
  selector: 'app-onb',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  templateUrl: './onb.component.html',
})
export class OnbComponent implements OnDestroy {
  receivedData: any;
  onbResponse = signal<any[]>([]);
  private sseSubscription?: Subscription;

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private onbService: OnbService,
  ) {
    const navigation = this.router.getCurrentNavigation();
    this.sseSubscription = this.onbService.run().subscribe({
          next: (data) => {
            this.onbResponse.update((values) => {
              if (!values) {
                return [data];
              }
              return [...values, data];
            });
            alert(this.onbResponse()); //this is updated correctly
          },
          error: (error) => {
            console.error('Received SSE error:', error);
          },
        });
    }
  }

@if (onbResponse().length == 0) {
    <p>loading</p>
} @else {
   {{onbResponse()}}strong text
}

I am receiving some data using a service and sse.
All this works since the code is triggered and the alert pops up.
The conditional rendering using signals and @if @else doesn't work.

The code looks fine to me, a working repro could help understand where the issue actually is.

Counterintuitively but this will result into "B".
const test: any[] = []

if(!test){
    console.log("A")
}else{
    console.log("B")
}

I figure you want to loose negation (Since you probably only want to append data if there is already some).
